# How to access the eclipse warnings and error messages via my plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

right now I am developing an eclipse plugin.

For my plugin I want to access the error messages and warnings eclipse shows the user, but I simply don't know how. In addtion I would like to change them and modify their output and/or their quickfix suggestion.

Is this possible?

Greetings,
Ogofo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is the `IMarker` interface. Eclipse calls them **resource markers**.

Take a look at the [IMarker](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IMarker.html) documentation for details.

Especial the `IMarker`s of type `org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker` will be interesting for you.

You can get the `IMarker` through the `IResource.findMarkers()`. Thus you can get `IMarker`s for `IProject`s, `IFile`s, `IFolder`s and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `IFile` (or anything derived from `IResource`) you can get the current error and other markers by calling the `findMarkers` method which gives you an array of `IMarker` objects.

However this will not allow you to do anything about the quick fix suggestions which would require a lot more work.

Comment: I think you will have to look at the Java Editor and Compiler interfaces (I am not familiar with these).